# build a list with different values in different indexes

Tags: python

I have a [predictions probabilities](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22762/understanding-predict-proba-from-multioutputclassifier) for multiclasses [0, 1], and I need to save the correct prediction probability for each row in my data set:

```
probs = model.predict_proba(X_test)
idx_1 = np.where(y_test == 1)[0]
idx_0 = np.where(y_test == 0)[0]
```

`probs` includes pairs of values, the first value in each pair is the probability for class 0 and the second  is the probability for class 1 (both summing up to 1).

The shape of probs differs cause am calling it during cross_validation, but let's take an example of one iteration: (568, 2) and for y_test: 568

I tried the following to save the correct probability for each labeled data:

`probs_per_class = [probs[idx_1, 1][i] if i in idx_1 else probs[idx_0, 0][i] for i in range(len(y_test))]`

but getting

> out of bound

error

if I expand it to simulate verbus mode:

```
        probs_per_class = []
        for i in range(len(y_test)):
            if i in idx_1:
                probs_per_class.append(probs[idx_1, 1][i])
                print(i, probs[idx_1, 1][i])
            elif i in idx_0:
                probs_per_class.append(probs[idx_0, 0][i])
                print(i, probs[idx_0, 0][i])
```

failing on:

> IndexError: index 194 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 191

What is going wrong?

Comment: You wrote a compact `[` list comprehension `]` which isn't working. So expand it into a more verbose `for` loop where you can insert debugging `print` statements. Also, you didn't share any of the essential debugging details, like the `.shape` of each data structure and which `i` value the exception was triggered on. Turn your question into a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you wish to invite collaborators to solve your problem.

Comment: Updated. hope it's more clear now

Answer (score 1):

You explained you have a `.shape` of `(568, 2)` at one point,
but that does not seem to be relevant to the reported error.

---

```
        for i in range(len(y_test)):
                ...
                probs_per_class.append(probs[idx_1, 1][i])
```

> What is going wrong?

The "IndexError: index 194 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 191"
diagnostic suggests that `y_test` has at least 194 elements,
yet `probs` is not that big.
(It also isn't clear just what the relationship between `idx_1` and `i`
might be, but there's room for either of them to be too big.)

Either make the related datastructures have the same `.shape`,
or operate on a subset of them.
For example, rather than `len(y_test)` you might
prefer `len(probs)`.

Note that `len(...)` is different from `.shape`.

Consider iterating over an `enumerate(...)` generator
instead of producing integer indexes,
so it will be much harder to accidentally fall off
the end of a datastructure that way.